# Why am I not getting any data using these HQL queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, hql, self-join

I use this query to pull the highest encounter from the highest chapter a user has reached:

```
SELECT COUNT(hc.s) as users, highest_chapter, highest_encounter
FROM
(
  SELECT s, MAX(l) as highest_chapter
  FROM appl9_evt
  WHERE month = "201508" AND st1 = "player" AND st2 = "level_progression" AND n = "level_start"
  GROUP BY s
  ORDER BY highest_chapter
) hc
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT s, l, MAX(get_json_object(json_data, '$.CurrentEncounter')) as highest_encounter 
  FROM appl9_evt
  WHERE month = "201508" AND st1 = "player" AND st2 = "level_progression" AND n = "level_start"
  GROUP BY s, l
  ORDER BY highest_encounter
) he ON hc.s = he.s AND hc.highest_chapter = he.l 
GROUP BY highest_chapter, highest_encounter
```

Then I save it as a table and try to get only version 2.2.1 (or whatever version, a self-join I think it's called) with this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT highest.s) as users, highest_chapter, highest_encounter FROM
(
  SELECT users as s, highest_chapter, highest_encounter 
  FROM augusers221
) highest
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT s 
  FROM appl9_cpu
  WHERE v_maj = '2.2.1'
) ver ON highest.s = ver.s
GROUP BY highest_chapter, highest_encounter
ORDER BY highest_chapter, highest_encounter
```

But there's something wrong with this second stage, because I can't pull any data... Thank you in advance for looking at this wall of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't be sure without sample data and the column names are unfriendly. But it seems the `s` column holds a user name or ID. Is that right?

If so, then you can't join it to the `augusers221.users` column because it is a count of users.

You could join the `appl9_cpu` table in the first query and I'll think you need to, because you've already lost the user names/IDs by the time of the second query.

```
SELECT COUNT(hc.s) as users, highest_chapter, highest_encounter
FROM
(
  SELECT s, MAX(l) as highest_chapter
  FROM appl9_evt
  WHERE month = "201508" AND st1 = "player" AND st2 = "level_progression" AND n = "level_start"
  GROUP BY s
  ORDER BY highest_chapter
) hc
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT s, l, MAX(get_json_object(json_data, '$.CurrentEncounter')) as highest_encounter 
  FROM appl9_evt
  WHERE month = "201508" AND st1 = "player" AND st2 = "level_progression" AND n = "level_start"
  GROUP BY s, l
  ORDER BY highest_encounter
) he ON hc.s = he.s AND hc.highest_chapter = he.l
INNER JOIN appl9_cpu cpu ON cpu.s = hc.s
WHERE cpu.v_maj = '2.2.1' 
GROUP BY highest_chapter, highest_encounter
```

If that doesn't help, then perhaps you can post some sample data.

Comment: That's great, thank you! It works. How would I now find this for DISTINCT s (users) only? where would I add DISTINCT? I can't use it together with GROUP BY, is that correct?

Comment: You are already grouping by `s` in the first sub-query `hc` where you get the highest chapters. So, it should be OK as-is.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see using this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1026d/3
 the problem is caused by using `SELECT COUNT(hc.s) as users,` when you later join that to `s` in `ON highest.s = ver.s`. So, you are joining the count to the actual value.

If you changed the column names to be more explicit, the issue may be clearer.